# Having errors when trying to select a specific column for a while loop, oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, while-loop, rownum

My table looks like this:

```
 ID |    NAME    |       STATUS
--------------------------------------
654 | 'FrankBot' | 'ready for assembly'
652 | 'TankBot'  | 'ready for assembly'
876 | 'StankBot' | 'waiting on parts'
123 | 'LankBot'  | 'ready for assembly'
444 | 'CrankBot' | 'waiting on parts'
```

And I want to be able to run the loop only if the status is waiting on parts at a certain row number, but this will run multiple times and change the status so i need to order them first so I don't mess up my count.

So I wrote this:

```
rownumber:= 1

while((select status 
     from (select status, rownum rnum 
           from (select status
                 from robotinventory 
                 order by status desc)) 
     where rnum = rowcounter) = 'waiting on parts') loop
```

However I have never used rownum before so i have no clue why I am getting these errors:

```
Error(12,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat

Error(17,33): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem    <an exponent (**)> and or group having intersect minus order    start union where connect || multiset
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `rownum` has nothing to do with your problems. You can't put a query of any sort in a `while` like you are trying to do. Your problem statement is very unclear. To loop through the results of a query in PL/SQL, the closest to what you are trying is the implicit cursor for loop. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155. Many options http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: Can you show your desired output?  I'm not following what you were hoping to see in the example above.